# Usb flash synchronization with Ubuntu-one

Tags: ubuntu-one

I want to synchronize my usb flash drive with the Ubuntu-one cloud. That is: Connect the usb flash disk and automatically have the synchronization started.

Comment: Cool. But... what is the question? I only see statements. If the question is: how do I do that? I could answer it :+

Comment: I have my files in home/something synchronise with the cloud. And I want to connect a usb stick and then synchronise it with the cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu One does not support synchronizing of files outside of your home directory at this time.